# NIC Team, Trunking, WS2012/HP2920

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, hp, nic

I have another problem. I made a NIC Team on Windows Server 2012 R2 containing 2 Interfaces. It's created as LACP.

Also, on Switch HP2920 I have two ports as a trunk (trk1), and also as LACP.

When I connect both ports from my Sever's NIC Team into both ports on the HP I don't have connection, furthermore, I can't even ping the gateway.

I turned on RSTP to check if it would help, but it didn't. Any ideas?

I thought if I made a NIC Team from two interfaces, they would work as "ONE," same on HP's trunk.

I need the NIC team for better speed and redundancy.

Best regards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: When you make a NIC team in Windows Server, you get a new network adapter with the team name, and it has default IP address settings. You need to put the IP address configuration from the original adapter into the new Team adapter - have you done that? Does the Windows NIC configuration screen show the team as connected, with green success icons, or red fail icons? does it show any LACP failure error messages?

Comment: Does your switch show any LACP status messages? e.g. How many PDU's it's sent/received? That can sometimes be a giveaway about the issue.

Comment: The problem is fixed.
It hasn't working, because with NIC Teaming you don't have to set a LACP on switch, just a regular trunk + static/dynamic on NIC, and everything is working :)
Thanks for answers